# Vue3 variable is assigned but never used when trying to pass props to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue newbie here. I'm trying to pass some props from parent to child, but I get the "variable is assigned a value but never used".

Parent:

```
<template>
  <TextBox :heading="heading1" :body="body1" />
</template>

<script>
import TextBox from "./components/TextBox.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TextBox,
  },

  setup() {
    const heading1 = ref("Primo titolo");
    const body1 = ref("Primo corpo del testo");
  },
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
<h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
<p>{{ body }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TextBox',
  props: {
    heading: String,
    body: String,
  }
}
</script>
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to import heading1 and body1 form parent.

Comment: you don't "import" props - but you're not importing anyway, so not sure why you say you're trying to import anything

Comment: you'll want to return  `heading1` and `body1` from `setup` I believe - i.e. `return { heading1, body1 };`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using composition API `setup` function you need to return, or you can use `data` function from options API :

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const heading1 = ref("Primo titolo");
    const body1 = ref("Primo corpo del testo");
    return { heading1, body1 }
  },
})
app.component('TextBox', {
  template: `
    <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
  `,
  props: {
    heading: String,
    body: String,
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <text-box :heading="heading1" :body="body1" />
</div>
```